# jQuery Click event not working with Submit button in a form

Tags: jquery

I have two submit button in a form I want to disable button2 on click (submit) & when user click button1, button2 will enable. Sorry for silly question I am newbie.

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).on("click", ".test2", function() {
                if ($('#test2').is(':visible')) {
                    $('#test2').hide();
                } else {
                    $('#test2').show();
                };
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="test" method="post">
    <input id="test" type="submit" value="button1" class="test1">
    <input id="test2" type="submit" value="button2"/>
</form>
```

Comment: please dont delete it. someone posted almost this exact question yesterday and deleted it before I (or anyone) had a chance to answer.

Comment: once hidden it will not visible, since you are using `click` `event` on same button which you want to hide, your **else** is useless in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicke event is bidden on class change it to id

```
$(document).on("click", "#test2", function()
```

Here is a sample code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on("click", "#test2", function (e) {
                if ($('#test2').is(':visible')) {
                    $('#test2').hide();
                    e.preventDefault();
                } else {
                    $('#test2').show();
                    e.preventDefault();
                };
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <form id="test" method="post">
        <input id="test" type="submit" value="button1" class="test1">
        <input id="test2" type="submit" value="button2" />
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not submitting the form.

Comment: @sadi then remove `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: @ shantaram_t removed, now it's submitting but not hiding.

Comment: If the button type is submit, it will submit the form on click. To avoid that I have included e.preventDefault. If that is removed, form will be submitted, but the button will not be hidden.

Comment: Is there any way to submit the form then hide the submit button?

Answer (score 1):

change
`$(document).on("click", ".test2", function() {`
to
`$(document).on("click", "#test2", function() {`

Once Button hidden, it will not visible, since you are using click event on same button which you want to hide, your **else** is useless in this case.

When you submit form, and came back to this form/page again, button will be visible to you.
I'm not clear what you are trying to do:
If you don't want to submit the form, and want to perform some more operation the you nedd to use:
`e.preventDefault();` as suggested by @Nitheesh and make it `display:none` or `disabled`

Answer (score 0):

How about this?
Add `disabled` to `#test2` and remove it when `#test` is clicked.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#test").on("click", function () {
    $("#test2").prop("disabled",false);
             });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <form id="test" method="post">
        <input id="test" type="button" value="button1" class="test1">
        <input id="test2" type="button" value="button2" disabled />
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change the js & html a bit.

Why? Cause if you want to disable the button2 on submit and enable it when the button1 is clicked, it's best to not put two submits in the `form`. We put one submit `button`, to trigger the `form` submit, and an `<a>` tag to enable the button2 (the `<a>` tag won't trigger the submit event again).

```
<form id="test" method="post">
  <a id="test1" href="#" class="btn btn-primary">button1</a>
  <button id="test2" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">button2</button>
</form>
```

And in the jQuery we do something like this inside your `$(document).ready()` function:

```
$('#test').on('submit', formSubmit);
$('#test1').on('click', unableButton);

function formSubmit () {
  $('#test2').prop('disabled', true);

 // Here you put the rules to submit your form 
}

function unableButton (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#test2').prop('disabled', false);
}
```

If you want i made this fiddle so you can see the code in action: https://jsfiddle.net/dobbinx3/Lu2ns80b/1/

Cya.